# What is the grammatical analysis of 信得过?

Tags: grammar

信 = to believe.
得过 = ???

Is this construction a sentence, a phrase, a verbalphrase or maybe sth. different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

信得过 means 'can be trusted/believed/depended upon'. I would actually classify it as a verbal phrase as there are usually more formal ways to express it in writing, such as 可靠 (dependable) or 可信 (believable).

I would say “他的话是信得过的！” if I wanted to say "His word could be trusted!"

Answer (score 3):

**信得过** literally refers to "Trust-worthy ", where 信 = trust, 得过 is an adjective means "able to / worthy"

You can say "他很可信" (He can be trusted) which means the same as "他很信得过" (He is trustworthy)

For the form **信得过**, we also say "**買得过**" (worth buying) and even "**嫁得过**" (worth marrying).

Comment: "買得过" (worth to buy) and "嫁得过" (worth to marry) sounds quite weird to me.

Comment: 買得过 and 嫁得过 are definitely ungrammatical and unheard of in Northern China. Can someone from Southern China confirm the usage?

Comment: 買得過, 嫁得過(的男人), 娶得過(的女人), 食得過(的食物), 睇得過(的電影) or even 選得過(的議員) .... all are common in Hong Kong.

Answer (score 1):

So if i got it right, 信得过 is a complex verb, wherein 信 is the main verb and 得过 the auxiliary verb?